# Connect to Dynamics CRM 2016(On-Premise) from Android

Tags: android, dynamics-crm

I want to integrate Android  application with Dynamics CRM 2015 Online and On-Premise.
For online version [Connect Android App to Dynamics CRM using Web API](http://scaleablesolutions.com/connect-android-app-to-dynamics-crm-using-web-api/) this works fine, But ADAL dependency is not supported for OnPremise.
Are there any resources which show the basic steps to access the Microsoft CRM on-premise.
Any sample code around same for connecting to REST endpoint will be helpful.

Comment: Why do you think its not supported?

Comment: @JamesWood adal library supports online version only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**On-Prem using ADAL:**

```
public static String GetAdfs(String url) throws IOException,
            ParserConfigurationException, SAXException {
        URL WsdlURL = new URL(url
                + "/XrmServices/2011/Organization.svc?wsdl=wsdl0");
        HttpURLConnection rc = (HttpURLConnection) WsdlURL.openConnection();

    rc.setRequestMethod("GET");
    rc.setDoOutput(true);

    InputStreamReader read = new InputStreamReader(rc.getInputStream());
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    int ch = read.read();
    while (ch != -1) {
        sb.append((char) ch);
        ch = read.read();
    }
    String response = sb.toString();
    read.close();
    rc.disconnect();

    DocumentBuilderFactory builderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory
            .newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder builder = builderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document x = builder
            .parse(new ByteArrayInputStream(response.getBytes()));

    NodeList nodes = x.getElementsByTagName("ms-xrm:Identifier");
    if (nodes.getLength() == 0)
        return null;

    return nodes.item(0).getFirstChild().getTextContent()
            .replace("http://", "https://");
}


// ADAL init
 AuthenticationContext authenticationContext = new AuthenticationContext(LoginActivity.this, GetAdfs(url), false);


authenticationContext.acquireToken(context, domain, Constants.CLIENT_ID, Constants.REDIRECT_URL, "", PromptBehavior.Auto, "", callback);

private AuthenticationCallback<AuthenticationResult> callback = new AuthenticationCallback<AuthenticationResult>() {

    @Override
    public void onError(Exception exc) {
        ViewHelper.showToast(context, "Domain name or user not available in ms crm");

    }

    @Override
    public void onSuccess(AuthenticationResult result) {
        if (result == null || result.getAccessToken() == null || result.getAccessToken().isEmpty()) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Token is Empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            Log.i(Keys.TOKEN_KEY, result.getAccessToken());
        }
    }
};
```

**1.** [**On-Prem and Online using Soap**](https://github.com/jlattimer/CRMSoapAuthJava)

**2.** [**On-Prem and Online using ADAL**](https://github.com/DynamicsCRM/Android-Activity-Tracker-for-Dynamics-CRM)

Answer (score 1):

Setup IFD for your on-premise deployment.

[Authenticate to Microsoft Dynamics 365 with the Web API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/mt595798.aspx)

> When you use the Web API for Dynamics 365 (online) or an **on-premises
>   Internet-facing deployment (IFD) you must use OAuth as described in
>   Connect to Microsoft Dynamics 365 web services using OAuth.**

[Connect to Microsoft Dynamics 365 web services using OAuth](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/gg327838.aspx)

> Applies To: Dynamics 365 (online), **Dynamics 365 (on-premises)**,
>   Dynamics CRM 2016, Dynamics CRM Online
>
> **The recommended authentication API for use with the Dynamics 365 Web
>   API is Azure Active Directory Authentication Library (ADAL)**, which is
>   available for a wide variety of platforms and programming languages.
>   The ADAL API manages OAuth 2.0 authentication with the Dynamics 365
>   web service identity provider. For more details on the actual OAuth
>   protocol used, see [Use OAuth to Authenticate with the CRM
>   Service](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/crm/archive/2013/12/12/use-oauth-to-authenticate-with-the-crm-service.aspx).

Comment: any reference on onprem+ifd for android

Answer (score 0):

ADFS is required for on prem. Check this documentation for how to set up the servers. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn531009(v=crm.7).aspx

If this is a one off project for a client it may also be worth creating a .Net based proxy between the app and CRM. That way you can use the .Net SDKs without worrying about losing support